# Closed set in metric spaces and their description in terms of convergent sequences

Tags: general-topology

So, I have the following Proposition:

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. A subset $A$ of $X$ is closed
in $(X, d)$ iff every convergent sequence of points in $A$ converges to a
point in $A$.

I am pretty confused by it's proof. It goes as follows:

In the first part the author (because it's an iff) proves that if $A$ is a closed set then every sequence converges to to a point inside that closed set. But the second part is quite obscure to me:

> Conversely, assume that every convergent sequence of points in $A$
>   converges to a point of $A$. Suppose that $X - A$ is not open. Then there 
>   exists a point $y ∈ X - A$ such that for each $ε > 0, B_ε (y) ∩ A \neq Ø$. 
>   For each positive integer $n$, let $x_n$ be any point in $B_{1/n} (y) ∩ A$. 
>   Then we claim that $x_n → y$. To see this let $ε$ be any positive real 
>   number, and $n_0$ any integer greater than $1/ε$. Then for each $n ≥ n_0, x_n ∈ B_{1/n} (y) ⊆ B_{1/n_0} (y) ⊆ B_ε (y)$. So $x_n → y$ and, by our 
>   assumption, $y \notin A$. This is a contradiction and so $X - A$ is
>   open and thus $A$ is closed in $(X, d)$.

The questions are:

- why the author claims that if $X-A$ is not open then there 
  exists a point $y ∈ X - A$ such that for each $ε > 0, B_ε (y) ∩ A \neq Ø$.
- why from that contradiction follows that $A$ is closed ?

Comment: $A$ is closed iff $X-A$ is open (this is a general fact about open and closed subsets, and in many cases it's used as the _definition_ of closed). What does it mean to be open, and what does that say about the $X-A$ in our case, which for contradiction is assumed to _not_ be open?

Comment: Thanks,  for everyone who answered this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1, by definition of open set, if $X-A$ is open, then $\forall y\in X-A$, there exists $\epsilon>0$, such that $B_{\epsilon}(y)\subset X-A$, that is $B_{\epsilon}(y)\cap A=\emptyset$. Hence the statement is just the negation of the definition.

For Q2, we know $A$ is closed iff $X-A$ is open. So it suffices to show $X-A$ is open. Then we assume it's not true and obtain a contradiction from the assumption.

Answer (score 0):

To the first question: Because the definition of open is "for every $y\in X\setminus A$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ so that $B_\epsilon(y) \subseteq X\setminus A$"

The negation of this, is "There exists a $y$ so that, for every $\epsilon>0$, $B_\epsilon(y)$ is not a subset of $X\setminus A$."

If $B_\epsilon(y)$ is not a subset of $X\setminus A$, then, it intersects $A$.

The contradiction comes from constructing a sequence, in $A$, which is convergent, but, its limit is not in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

$X - A$ is open if:

$\forall y \in X-A$,  $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that
$B_{\epsilon}(y) \subset X-A$.

This is equivalent to:

$\forall y \in X-A$,  $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that
$B_{\epsilon}(y) \cap A = \emptyset$.

So the negation of $X - A$ is open is:

$\exists y \in X-A$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$ such that
$B_{\epsilon}(y) \cap A \ne \emptyset$.

The contradiction proves that $X-A$ is open, so the complement of $X - A$ is closed by definition. Since $A \subset X$, the complement of $X - A$ is $A$, so $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

- If a set $U$ is not open, then $U^\circ \neq U$. Pick a point $y\in U\setminus U^\circ$ and then for every $\epsilon > 0$, $B_\epsilon(y)\not\subset U$. So $B_\epsilon(y)\cap(X\setminus U)\neq\phi$
- $U$ is open in $X$ $\iff$ $X\setminus U$ is closed